# How to set image postition as fixed in gridview

Tags: android, image, gridview

I have on gridview for displaying number of images just like a gallery in android mobiles.

But when I scroll down to lower part of gridview the position of displaying images are changing.

My custom Adapter..

```
class MyCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModelBean> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final List<ModelBean> listDownload;

    public MyCustomArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<ModelBean> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.gridview_layout, list);

        this.context = context;
        this.listDownload = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView imageView;
        protected ProgressBar pb;
        protected ModelBean mb;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.pb = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.imageView.setTag(listDownload.get(position).getImage());
        holder.imageView.setId(position);

        PbAndImageBean pb_and_imageBean = new PbAndImageBean();
        pb_and_imageBean.setImg(holder.imageView);
        pb_and_imageBean.setPb(holder.pb);
        pb_and_imageBean.setModelBean(listDownload.get(position));
        new DownloadImageAsyncTask(context).execute(pb_and_imageBean);

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));

        return convertView;
    }

class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    int _postion;

    // constructor
    public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
        this._postion = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // on selecting grid view image
        // launch full screen activity
        Intent i = new Intent(context, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("position", _postion);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

I have used lazy loading concept to get images from server , 
so single image gets downloaded at single time.
But logically it doesn't affect on my problem.

What i want to do is , when an image get downloaded at any position it should get locked at that particular position , will solve my problem.

Comment: Finally .. Universal Image loader solved my problem... Thank you all....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this-

```
class MyCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModelBean> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final List<ModelBean> listDownload;

    public MyCustomArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<ModelBean> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.gridview_layout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.listDownload = list;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        imageView.setTag(listDownload.get(position).getImage());
        imageView.setId(position);
        PbAndImageBean pb_and_imageBean = new PbAndImageBean();
        pb_and_imageBean.setImg(imageView);
        pb_and_imageBean.setPb(pb);
        pb_and_imageBean.setModelBean(listDownload.get(position));
        new DownloadImageAsyncTask(context).execute(pb_and_imageBean);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        int _postion;
        // constructor
        public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
            this._postion = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // on selecting grid view image
            // launch full screen activity
            Intent i = new Intent(context, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("position", _postion);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very close to solve but.....when i scroll down it disappears images...please help on this...

Comment: @Priyanka Where are you ?

Answer (score 0):

Change this one.

```
    View view = null;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        viewHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: what is change in it?

Comment: You haven't seen? In your code u haven't create object for View Holder when your view is null so every time your view recycled when you scrolled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60517/discussion-between-anupamaj-and-pg-android).

Comment: First Assign convertView like-
View view = convertView ;
and than check condition like -
if (view == null) {
}

Comment: @Priyanka I have tried this before...But what is logic behind this?

Comment: I just corrected above answer. You can also direct use convertView  without assigning it in any other view and logic behind is: You should check that this view is not-null and of an appropriate type before using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display the correct data, this method can create a new view. Heterogeneous lists can specify their number of view types, so that this View is always of the right type.and Always reuse The old view, if possible.

Comment: @Priyanka But This doesn't solve my problem... My problem is the images are mixing up or keep changing after scroll....